What does "break an arm" mean?
As Sidney Falcon enters the room, Mr. Weldon contacts his assistant. Sidney
discreetly shakes his head, instructing the assistant not to inform Mr.
Weldon of his presence:

Assistant: It's the third time he's called today.
Sidney: Probably wants me to break a leg.
Assistant: No, an arm, he said.

In this dialogue between Sidney Falcon and his assistant, when the assistant mentions
that Mr. Weldon said he wants Sidney to ‘break an arm’, what could this phrase
imply in their conversation?

It's just a bit of darkish humour.  Sidney delivers his line jokingly, "What, he wants me to break someone's leg?! Hah! As if!" and the reply is a dead serious "No, actually an arm".  It's just a joke where a euphemism becomes real.

Sidney's client is desperate for good publicity and has hired him because he has a proven track record of planting stories into the Hunsecker Column, the 'go to' destination for the city's club-going public to decide which nightspots to visit (and which to avoid).
Sidney doesn't write the column though, he only has influence and not the ability to command a story. His client seems to think that, having paid him, he has a right to expect that the story will appear soon.
Sidney, sarcastically, asks his secretary if his client thinks he's going to act like a mafioso and break Hunsecker's leg in order to force him to comply to his wishes and print a story. She replies that they did literally say that he should break his arm.


SALLY: That's the third time he's called today.
SIDNEY: He wants me to break a leg?
SALLY: (literally): No, an arm, he said. (then) I told him you were sure the item would be in Mr. Hunsecker's column in tomorrow's...
SIDNEY: (interrupting, sharply) It isn't.  I've just seen the early edition.

Note that both Sidney and his client, Weldon, are using the terms hyperbolically. He offers it as an example of "I can't force them", and the client is using it metaphorically to mean "he should exert every single piece of influence that he has at his disposal".

That all being said, Weldon is possibly also subtly threatening Sidney here. It's clear that he's a legitimate businessman and it may not be the first time that he's actually been involved in a little light arm-twisting. Certainly the next time he sees Sidney, he applies some physical force to him.

[Sidney slips through the congestion, but just as he tries to enter the
Club, Weldon's hand shoots out, neatly ambushing him, pulling him
aside into the narrow courtyard.  Sidney is instantly resentful of
this manhandling, but has to adjust himself, assuming a quick smile
for the benefit of Weldon.]
Sweet Smell of Success - Screenplay


It is also a bit of a pun, referencing the ironic way of wishing a theatre actor good luck by saying "Break a leg".

@JaapScherphuis - I thought about mentioning that, but the context here is very much 'coercion through force'. "He wants me to [(threaten to) break Hunsecker's leg if he won't print my story]!?"

It is not clear from your answer, but is Sidney afraid the client is going to want to break his leg/arm for not getting the story published soon enough, or that the client expects Sidney to break someone else's arm/leg for him to get the story out?

@JaapScherphuis - Sidney is asking if his client expects him to (threaten to) break Hunsecker's leg, to coerce him to print the story.

Yes, in that case the theatrical meaning is not so much in play.

I see no connection whatsoever to the theater expression.  It's just a straightforward "euphemism to literal" standard joke.
